# Visual Studio 2019: Start Page instead of Start Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio introduced a blocking `Start Window` instead of a non-blocking `Start Page`.

Considering how extensible Visual Studio is, is there a way to have VS2019 display a non-blocking `Start Page`.

The new `Start Window` is quite annoying, less informative, displays all projects, not just solutions, pinning is not up to previous standards, and no additional information. Most annoying is the blocking aspect.

I am thinking that there is some sort of extension or setting that Microsoft has somewhere, which can re-enable the `Start Page` and disable the `Start Window`.

**Alternatively** if it is not possible, is it possible to just disable the `start window` and have the main application appear, when the app starts or when a user closes a solution/project?

--
Another hope with this post is that Microsoft sees this request and maybe modifies their code and offers users an option at the start, much like color theme and default code set, as to whether they want app blocking or app non-blocking for the start area.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at setting page on TOOLS->OPTIONS->ENVIRONMENT->STARTUP and there you have several options.

Comment: @DAme The `Empty Environment` option is the best, as that works for initial and upon closing a project/solution, just no start page, but better. Thank you! The 2017 start page was so far the best.

Answer (score 20):

In Tools > Options > Environment > Startup > On startup, open: select "Empty environment".

Visual Studio will start without showing the modal Start Window.

Comment: This also prevents the start window from showing when you close a solution

Answer (score 5):

[Start Page on startup](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JanKucera.StartPageOnStartup) extension restores the traditional Start Page in VS 2019.

[Start Page: Please give it back!](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/434456/start-page-please-give-it-back.html) and [Make the Visual Studio 2019 start window non-modal](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/435168/make-the-visual-studio-2019-start-window-non-modal.html) are open issues concerning your other points.

Comment: The `Start Page Extension` looks good, however where is the menu item that brings back the page if a user closes the page? Does a user have to restart VS to get the page back once closed? Separately, looks awesome. The people responsible for the modal non-informative window should be fired. Thank you.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger You can call File.StartPage from the command window or create a menu command for it with my Visual Commander extension.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I could not find any VCmd menu after installing the `Visual Commander` extension. Please elaborate.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger In VS 2019 it's under the main Extensions menu: https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2019/04/25/extensions-in-the-main-visual-studio-2019-menu/

Comment: This no longer works, it appears Microsoft removed the start page entirely and the extension has now been removed from the marketplace. The only alternative appears to be [Start Page+](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YannDuran.StartPagePlus) which, while functional, is cosmetically different from the previous start page. It looks like we can only hope Microsoft decides to re-introduce the start page in a future release, although it doesn't look likely at this point.

Comment: removed? its my entry point to go to Developer news!