# How to restore normal "New Project" windows on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 I noticed the very unpleasant change of the "new project" window, as [announced here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/new-start-window-and-new-project-dialog-experience-in-visual-studio-2019/). As with much of the community I totally hate the new useless window and would pretty much prefer to use the normal old one.

To show what I'm refering to, here are screenshots of the old and the new screens:

VS 2017 and earlier:
[image: VS2017 new project]

VS 2019:
[image]

This is somewhat similar to [this other question asking about the start page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56241077/2557263), but this time, it's about the new project dialog.

How can I restore the old, full featured dialog instead of the broken new one?

Comment: Maybe Microsoft leaves an undocumented switch to restore that. But either you get used to the new one, and report its issues to Microsoft, or you go back to VS2017. This is not a good question for SO.

Comment: @LexLi I'm trying to keep VS2019 (it's great on some other features), but without this annoyance. Besides, we all know that Microsoft just ignores all its users and their feedback.

Comment: Then I don't know why you posted here. SO has no magic over Microsoft as well.

Comment: @LexLi I posted here simply because the question is perfectly fine for SO, as [reflected here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Of course MS will just ignore this forum, almost like their own, but here I'm asking not Microsoft, but the Stack Overflow community. The other question I linked is a good example of what I'm looking for, if it exists.

Comment: One of examples where something is terribly over engineered. Also, an example where the team doesn't listen to the community. Shame. Did a quick survey in few teams and found literally no one that would say a good word about this new "invention".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Officially it is not possible and Microsoft ignores [all negative feedback about it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/redesigning-the-new-project-dialog/).

But there is now an [extension called Classic 'New Project' Dialog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softworkz.SwitchProjectDialog) that brings back the old **and better tree based dialog**:

After installing the extension, enable it in Settings

[image]

you can use it when you create a new project

[image]

I tested it in VS 2019 Update 2 Preview 1 and it works fine.

Comment: has there been any reasoning to explain these changes?

Comment: @LuckyLikey I have no idea. Looks like Microsoft wants to reinvent the wheel but forgot features. Read the blog post for the pseudo arguments from Microsoft.

Comment: I can't understand why Microsoft thinks this new project dialog is better, it is harder to use in every way.

Comment: Only works with VS 2019.