# How to create Projects from online-templates in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2019

I'm currently trying to set up an `Asp .NET Core 2.1` Project with an `angular` frontend, using this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-an-angular-7-app-with-asp-net-core-2-1/). It's the same, I've been using some time ago with Visual Studio 2017.

The Tutorial asks me to use the Online-Template `Angular 7 .NET Core 2 Template`. However in Visual Studio 2019 I cannot find the option to create a project from using online-templates.

How can I do this in VS19? I think it should be really trivial, but I can't find any relevant information on google. The only hints I found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-new-project?view=vs-2019), is to either clone a repository or `Install more tools and features` Using the Visual Studio Installer. I have Web-Development enabled and can't find any option there to enable online-templates.

[image]

I know, that the [template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LuisTepepa.Angular7CoreTemplate) itself is only compatible with Visual Studio 2017. But since I'm able to work on existing projects, that I created using Visual Studio 2017, I assume that there must be an easy way to create those projects.

I've also tried to use the `dotnet new angular -o my-new-app` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). But this template still uses anguar 5. So I'd have to update angular to version 7 first. This involves changes to the whole project structure, like switching `angular-cli.json` to `angular.json` and other things.

Comment: [restore the old dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335266/1466046)

Comment: @magicandre1981 this worked. Incredible, that Microsoft deleted such a convenient feature like this, just like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore normal "New Project" windows on Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262172/how-to-restore-normal-new-project-windows-on-visual-studio-2019)

Answer (score 2):

You can download a plugin that will make the create new project look like the classic one:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softworkz.SwitchProjectDialog

Comment: ty, but the Information is already included in @magicandre1981 's comment