# Can't use Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-setup-proje

I need to create a Windows setup (.msi) with Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects.
I have installed the VS extension but it seems that I can't use (I can't find a way to add a setup project, I tried lot of keywords without any success).
I'm using VS 2019 Version 16.9.0.
I have used the installer for several years on VS2017 without any problem but may be I'm wrong because I don't know well the new opening GUI.
How can I solve my trouble? Thank you.

[image: No option Installer]

[image: Component is installed]

Comment: this new dialog is crap, use the [classic tree based one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335266/1466046)

Comment: have you tried the old style dialog?