# Xamarin.Android class library missing when create project Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, class-library

I am trying to build a Xamarin native android class library in C# to make some of my customized android widgets available across projects. I was able to do it with VS 2017 like below.

[image]

But I was not able to find this kind of project when creating in VS 2019. See the picture below. I can only create Xamarin.Android app but not class libraries.

[image]

When I really tried I could even find what I wanted in F#, as shown below. But I don't know F#. I didn't even remember choosing F# when installing VS 2019.

[image]

I have to move to VS2019 because my project that refereces ScandIt library cannot compile in VS 2017. But I ran into this problem. I suppose I could create that class library project in VS2017 and then work on it in VS2019 but that feels frustrating. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

I'm using VS2019 16.9.3 in Windows 10.

Edit:
Found another guy with similar problem (he can't find binding library). Not sure if the same patch applies to me. Will just have to wait.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-find-Xamarin-Android-Binding-Libr/1363176?space=8&q=android+binding&viewtype=all

Comment: this new dialog is crap, use the [classic tree based one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335266/1466046)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Legendary! I couldn't understand why people talk about how broken these new MS products are until now. I don't mind the new look. But missing feature... is infuriating. Can you post your answer so I can accept it? For the poor blokes from future.

Comment: no new answer as it is a duplicate. I don't want to repeat myself again

Comment: idk what's the issue with your VS, but I can find the `Android Class Library` in my VS19, posting the pic below in answer section, gonna delete it once you acknowledge it.

Comment: Actually I think Blu is right. Even with classic view I couldn't find the project template. I must've misread it last night.

Comment: @LionetChen VS team has addressed the problem and the fix is pending release. Please check:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-find-Xamarin-Android-Binding-Libr/1363176?space=8&q=android+binding

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed with [Update 16.9.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.9.4)

> Added back missing Xamarin templates (iOS/Android Class Library,
> iOS/Android Bindings Library, Android Wear, Xamarin.UITest) in the New
> Project dialog. These templates were hidden by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just want to show you that I can find the library un my VS19.

The simple thing is, I just search for `library` & it was present over there, after adding the same filters as shown by you, the Library was on the top.

[image: VS19]

------------------- EDIT----------------------------

> Versions of VS

[image: Old]

[image: New]

Comment: What is your VS version? Mine's 16.9.3. Apparently it could be relevant. See my edit.

Comment: my version numbers - 16.8.4/16.9.3 i can find that library in both versions

Comment: Note that one of your versions is Enterprise. I don't know if that is relevant, but I do know that I am using Community.